# How to add the current slide number plus the total slides in Keynote?

Tags: macos, keynote

I am wondering how I could achieve something like that in the current version of Keynote for OSX:

For example the current slide is 3 and the total slides are 10.
And I want to show it like **(3 / 10)** and so on.

I could do it manually, but is there some automation for it?

Answer (score 7):

Keynote has no such feature (counting the total number of slides).

Semi-manual solution: Add the total number of slides as a text-box " /10"in your Master configuration. Place it next to the automatic slide number that Keynote generates.

Answer (score 2):

X of Y may not work. But solely X page could.
I've just configure this feature on keynote follow the answer below, it did worked.

Answer: http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/keynote-how-to-add-pagenumber-on-the-sheet.341924/

Someone asked same question almost ten years before at macrumors. Thanks Google.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to edit the master configuration, you can also add the total number of slides a text box, and simply copy and paste it on each slide. Keynote should automatically insert the pasted textbox at the correct position.